# Which is better practice: 'check whether a primary ID exists then skip' or 'insert ignore'?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I'm writing a system which checks an API for new messages every *n* minutes, which is the better practice? (Each message has a unique ID which is used as the primary ID in my system.)

Would you prefer to:

1. Look up the primary ID of the message in the database and skip inserting the message it if it already exists
2. Do 'Insert Ignore'?

Comment: can you show us the table create code?

Comment: I think the answer may depend on what your system needs to do if it already exists. I personally would avoid insert ignore as it discards it silently and that just seems like a bad process.

Comment: "which checks an API for new messages every n minutes" - Are you processing these messages like they were in a queue and processing may have side-effects?

Comment: *system which checks an API for new messages every n minutes* I understand this words as "retrieve info about messages (with unknown IDs) which occures in DB after previous check" - but later you tell about insertion... unclear.

Comment: The look up idea doesn't work. What if user B inserts while user A is 'looking up'?

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your solutions.  Keep reading.

Let the database do the work.  If you don't want duplicates, then create unique index on the columns.  My guess is:

```
create unique index unq_messages_messageid on messages (mesageid);
```

(This will also work on the string or multiple columns, if that is what you really want.)

Once you have the unique index or constraint the following are the two methods I would suggest.

(1) Just do an insert.  If there is a duplicate, it will fail.  Handle the error in your application code.  Good application code handles errors.

(2) Use `on duplicate key update` (this might one day be replaced by `on conflict ignore`):

```
insert into messages ( . . . )
    values ( . . .)
    on duplicate key update message_id = values(message_id);
```

The assignment is a no-op -- it does nothing.

Why is this preferred over `insert ignore`?  Simple reason:  it only handles the specific error of a duplicate key.  Other errors that might occur are still returned to the application.

Comment: Not sure why you're telling me I need a unique ID. How would my `insert ignore` work unless I already had a unique ID?

Comment: "Just do an insert. If there is a duplicate, it will fail." That's exactly what `insert ignore` does, but without producing an error message. If I already have the message, there's no error and nothing to handle.

Comment: `on duplicate key update` is not required in this use case. Messages are not updated.

Comment: @AmbroseChapel . . . `insert ignore` ignores ALL errors, not just duplicate key errors.  If you want something unique, then the database should enforce the uniqueness, not the application (if you really care).  `on duplicate key` ignores precisely the one error you care about, rather than all possible errors.